# Prevent CSS from overwriting JS CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, libraries

I'm a PHP guy and new to js libraries.

I installed widgEditor, a text input editor, on my website. However, the result has no bold or italicized buttons; it is simply an unordered list.

The only thing I can think of happening is my CSS is overwriting the JS CSS. Is that possible?

Here is a demo:
http://www.aaron-schpitzer.ca/en/events/add

Comment: And yes I have corrected the CSS path in the .js and also double checked the image paths in the CSS

Comment: @Amadan I meant the CSS that javascript(JS) is executing/calling or whatever, I'm not familliar with JS sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

widgEditor comes with its own CSS files, which are not linked in your page (nor loaded in any other way). More correctly, `widgContent.css` is being loaded, but `widgEditor.css` is not (and I suspect that the editor's style definitions would be in there).